# Keeping Visual Studio Codespaces running on its own for longer than 2 hours?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-virtual-machine, vscode-remote, codespaces

I am running Python scripts in a Visual Studio Codespace (Azure) Linux machine, to achieve faster execution time compared to running these scripts in my laptop.

The problem is, the codespace is suspended after 2 hours unless I manually take other actions in the codespace within this time. 2 hours seems to be the maximum auto-suspend delay you can set, and then execution is stopped before completion.

**Is there any way to set a longer auto-suspend delay, or to introduce an action in my program which refreshes the auto-suspend countdown?**

When creating a Codespace or changing settings of an existing Codespace, three options pop up for "Auto-Suspend Delay" in the VS Code dialog box at the top:

`5 minutes
30 minutes
2 hours`

I have tried setting a different amount, both as a plain number and as a number followed by "hours" or "minutes". In both cases, an error is shown: `"Change Codespace Settings: Selection is invalid"`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to run a codespace continuously at this time. You must select one of the auto-suspend options and the codespace will suspend if you're not actively using it, such as typing or interacting with it in some way.